# Inconsistency when dereferencing returned empty shared_ptr

Tags: c++, null, return-value, shared-ptr, dereference

I recently noticed some strange behavior when using a returned empty shared_ptr. To illustrate the problem consider this example:

```
    struct A {
      A() { }
      void foo() {
        std::cout << "A::foo" << std::endl;
      }
    };

    struct B {
      B() :i(42) { }
      void foo() {
        std::cout << "B:foo with i: " << i << std::endl;
      }

      int i;
    };

    template<typename T>
    std::shared_ptr<T> create_empty() {
      return std::shared_ptr<T>(); 
    }
```

Then calling:

```
    std::shared_ptr<A> pa(create_empty<A>());
    pa->foo(); // #1: Works fine and prints: "A::foo".

    std::shared_ptr<B> pb(create_empty<B>());
    pb->foo(); // #2: Throws an exception.
```

Now my question is why call #1 works (I expected to get an exception as well) and if this is the correct behavior how to prevent #1 from working. Am I supposed to check if the return value is empty? Are there some other ways to return null or empty shared_ptr? I'm using MSVC++ 11 if that matters...

Comment: C++ generally doesn't add expensive checks without explicit request from the user. You're entirely free to add `if (pa)` to your code at your own discretion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code in both cases dereferences a null pointer. The behavior is undefined, so anything can happen, including things that seem to make sense. Don't try to make sense out of them. Undefined is undefined.

Comment: OK I understand - guess I got little bit confused. So there must be checking before dereferencing the return value. Thanks a lot for your answer.

Comment: @mkh - there's no checking (well, formally, no reason to check, but no compiler checks this). That's the pointe of undefined behavior: no need to check for it, just let whatever happens happen.

Comment: @mkh - oh, sorry, I just realized what you said: yes, if you want to access the thing, you need to check.

Answer (score 1):

None of the examples really work, as they are using a null pointer.

In the first case, you really don't access anything from A, so you might not notice. In the second case, accessing the `i` member will extremely likely have to dereference the `this` pointer (and the system will notice that it is null).